# merge sort / сортировка слиянием

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь реализовать сортировку слиянием. Общий принцип довольно понятен, но в процессе реализации возникли проблемы. Необходимо реализовать так, что бы в процессе создавалось как можно меньше массивов, ведь так?

Идея была в том, что бы создать временный двумерный массив `result`. В него циклически записывать результат слияния двух подмассивов из оригинальногго `unsortArr`. Когда первый круг слияния прошел, приравниваем наш `unsortArr` к  `result` (в котором, как помним, хранится результат попарного слияния первого круга). Обновляем переменные (`result`) включительно, и повторяем шаги.

**Реализация внизу где-то зациклена.**

Может моя идея в целом неверное исполнение marge_sort? В сети много примеров на С/С++, но в контексте js это все немного не то. Или у меня где-то ошибка при работе с двумерными массивами?

Буду благодарна за подсказки, в глазах уже рябит.

```js
console.log('Begin \n');

const unsortArr = [8, 5, 1, 7, 4, 9, 3, 10, 2, 6];
const length = unsortArr.length;

function merge(arr) {
  let l = arr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    arr[i] = [arr[i]];
  }
  return arr;
}
let l = Math.floor(unsortArr.length / 2);

function sort(arr) {
  var result = [], //массив для хранения отсортированых подмассивов
      j = 0; // индекс вставки в результат отсортированного подмассива
      
  //перебираем все подмассивы попарно
  for (let i = 0; i <= l; i += 2) {
    var leftIndex = 0, // индекс левого массива
      rightIndex = 0; //индекс правого массива
      
    console.log('\n' + 'lets start for ' + i);

    // создаем подмассив в j ячейке
    result[j] = new Array();

    //до тех пор, пока не 'сольётся' хотя бы один массив, проводить поэлементное сравнение двух подмассивов  
    while ((leftIndex <= arr[i].length) || (rightIndex <= arr[i + 1].length)) {
      if (arr[i][leftIndex] > arr[i + 1][rightIndex]) {
        result[j].push(arr[i + 1][rightIndex]);
        result[j].push(arr[i][leftIndex]);
        rightIndex++;
      }
      if (arr[i][leftIndex] < arr[i + 1][rightIndex]) {
        result[j].push(arr[i][leftIndex]);
        result[j].push(arr[i + 1][rightIndex]);
        leftIndex++;
      }
      if (arr[i][leftIndex] === arr[i + 1][rightIndex]) {
        result[j].push(arr[i][leftIndex]);
        result[j].push(arr[i + 1][rightIndex]);
        leftIndex++;
        rightIndex++;
      }
    } // конец цикла while

    //у одного из массивов мог остаться отсортированный "хвост" надо его найти и приклеить к результату
    if (leftIndex !== arr[i].length - 1) {
      result[j].concat(arr[i].slice(leftIndex));
    }
    if (rightIndex !== arr[i + 1].length - 1) {
      result[j].concat(arr[i + 1].slice(rightIndex));
    }
    console.log('\n result j = ' + result[j]);
    j++;

  }
  
  
  // arr = result;
  return arr;
//   if (length == arr[0].length ){
//   return arr;
// }
// else sort(arr);
}

console.log(merge(unsortArr));

console.log('\n' + sort(unsortArr) );
```

Comment: `while ((leftIndex <= arr[i].length) || (rightIndex <= arr[i + 1].length))` уверены что ИЛИ а не И? Вам же нужно пока оба фрагмента не слиты. Ну и в целом замечание. При сортировки массивы создавать заного каждый раз - плохая идея в плане производительности.

Comment: @pavel по логике должно работать ИЛИ. т.к. может произойти ситуация, когда один из массивов полностью влился, а второй отсортированный я потом просто конкантенирую.
Вот с точки зрения производительности и все беды. Думала это самое оптимальное перезаписывать цикл результата после каждого круга слияний всех подмассивов. Получается, методы вроде .slice .splice .map так же не использовать, т.к. они создают новый массив?

Comment: нет, как раз по логике будет И. Если 1 списка нету, то его потом вливают. Вообще сортировка слиянием обычно на 2 массивах и 4 указателях (индексах) пишется.

Comment: @pavel действительно И. Похоже лучше буду колупать чужие реализации. Спасибо за помощь!